# When do the groups associated with an LDAP user get updated in Artifactory?

Tags: ldap, artifactory

RE:  https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/when-do-the-groups-associated-with-an-ldap-user-get-updated-in-artifactory/

The Knowledge Base article above says:

"LDAP user authentication requests using Encrypted password or plain text password will update the LDAP group association changes from the LDAP server."

We've added a user to a group, but that user still can't see the artifacts governed by that group even after he has logged in.  How can we cause Artifactory to update its group membership cache?

Answer (score 1):

Please ask the user to logout and log back in after being added to the groups. Artifactory will try to reach to the LDAP server for validating the creds and then get the groups associated with the user which is returned from the LDAP server.
There is a chance that LDAP cache as mentioned in here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/LDAP#LDAP-Non-UIAuthenticationCache might take effect the groups to be associated if the user session is not hitting the LDAP server.